# Process states in operating system and resource utilization

Tags: process, operating-system

What is a difference between sleep,wait and suspending a process in OS? Does any of these states consume resources or waste CPU cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all three cases, the process is not runnable, so it does not consume CPU.  THe process is not returned to the runnable state until some event happens.  The difference is what that event is:

- Sleep: This can describe two different things.  Either a process is runnable after a certain (fixed) period of time elapses, or the process is runnable after the device itself wakes up from a power saving mode.
- Wait: process is runnable after something finishes.  That something is usually an I/O operation (disk, network) completing.
- Suspend: either the OS or another process takes the process out of the run state.  This can overlap with "Sleeping" above.

Processes in all three states don't consume CPU time, but they do consume memory unless the process is entirely paged out.  And processes in the wait state may be consuming I/O resources.

Comment: Very elegantly clarified, and your exact,but short explanation in the last paragraph was awesome... Upvoted,+1.